# Comparing if 2 URLs have the same original target

Tags: java

I have two urls as Java Strings suppose "youtube.com" and "goo.gl/ur2l"  and I want to make a function

```
boolean isSame(String url1, String url2)
```

which returns weather both urls direct to the same url at the end or not.
how would that be implemented in java ?

Comment: Well, how would you do it as a human? If I gave you two urls and asked you to check, what would you do? What steps would you follow? Ok, there's your algorithm. Now, which of these steps do you need more help with in Java, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a HTTP request for each URL and check the HTTP code. If it's a redirect (`30*`), extract the `Location` HTTP header, that should be the "original" URL.

Comment: But then recursive. I can tinyurl a goo.gl that refers to a shorturl that redirects to the original website. Which then just moved.

Answer (score 1):

you need to translate the string to ip address and than compare them.
Something like that:

```
   InetAddress address = null;

    byte[] ip = new byte[0];

    try {
    address = InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
    ip = address.getAddress();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can see, that doesn't work, since what I understood that OP wants is that HTTP redirects are taken into account.

Comment: In this case, the client only familiar to the proxy. you will receive the IP of the computer that is open to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I just shortened http://www.youtube.com URL to http://bit.ly/9b2Y3D. Now when I access the latter using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) I get:

```
$ curl http://bit.ly/9b2Y3D
[...]
> GET /9b2Y3D HTTP/1.1
[...]
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved
[...]
< Location: http://youtube.com/
```

You see, the shortened URL returns 302 as opposed to 200 OK. Also the `Location` header is quite interesting. I think you have a lot of information now for starters. Try HttpClient and extract the status code and `Location`. Then look at [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class,e specially how it implements [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 1):

You need follow the 302 redirect until find some 200 http code. Please put a configuration to avoid follow infinite redirects :)